# Is it possible for UserDefaults.standard.removeObject(forKey: ) to fail?

Tags: ios, swift

I was trying to reproduce a strange bug in one app I'm working on, and it seems the only possible reason for the bug to happen would be that `UserDefaults` sometimes fails to remove the object.

```
UserDefaults.standard.removeObject(forKey: Constant.name1)
UserDefaults.standard.removeObject(forKey: Constant.name2)
```

When I test using the code above, it is working fine on my end, but it seems that there is some case (iOS version? Memory conditions? Other?) where this code fails for some of our users, and the app keeps those UserDefaults forever.

Is that even possible?

I found some radars on OpenRadar that points towards the fact that `UserDefaults` are not saving correctly, but no confirmation that it really happens.

Comment: Call this method UserDefaults.standard.synchronize() after remove key.

Comment: From the official documentation, it says synchronize() is obsolete https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/userdefaults/1414005-synchronize `this method is unnecessary and shouldn't be used.`

Comment: for my opinion is that Apple now does synchronize from time to time, but they do not synchronize when going into background any more.This now means that the following can happen: Apple synchronizes the user defaults, you write a new value, app goes into background (user defaults are not synchronized), app gets killed with any reason (for example due to memory pressure). Now your value was not saved or update. So just synchronize when the app goes into background. There is no need to call synchronize at any other time! Do not call synchronize all the time, it will kill app performance

Comment: @DixitAkabari hmm when apple clearly says "this method is unnecessary and shouldn't be used.", and you have your opinion... apple wins

Comment: @Mathbl can it be multi-threading issue, e.g. removing/adding/changing those settings at the same time from 2 threads?

Comment: @Mathbl: Did you able to find the issue ? I am also facing the same issue. The bug is rare and I could not even reproduce the bug.